# how to use ssh agent forwarding

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ssh-agent

I have three systems , a client that only install ssh client and server_1 and server_2 . im using ssh public authentication and i can ssh from client to both server_1 and server_2.
i saved same pub key for server 1 and  and now i want to ssh from server 1 to server 2 using agent forwarding and i want my private key stay only on client please help me ASAP how can i do this scenario ?
i use this link but dont know how to do it .

[An Illustrated Guide to SSH Agent Forwarding: Public Key Access with Agent Forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd)

Answer (score 4):

First you have to invoke `ssh-agent` on your client to make it remember your key

```
ssh-agent -t 3600 ~/.ssh/private_key_rsa
```

(assuming that your key is stored in `~/.ssh/private_key_rsa`, you can also leave out the `-t 3600` if you want infinite lifetime)

then you simply ssh into one of your servers using the `-A` option

```
ssh -A server1
```

from there you will then be able to ssh into server2

```
ssh server2
```

If you do not want to specify the `-A` option everytime you can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`  (on the client and optionally both servers)

```
Host server1
 ForwardAgent yes

Host server2
 ForwardAgent yes
```

This works for any number of servers. To keep the `~/.ssh/config` short you can introduce wildcards e.g.

```
Host server?
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: What about server3?

Comment: This works for any number of servers. (see also my recent edit). If all servers accept the same key you can do `ssh -A server1` from there `ssh -A server2` from there `ssh -A server3` and so on.

Comment: For anyone else having a brain fart moment: If you set up agent forwarding for a user, and then run sudo ssh it won't work because you're running ssh as root

Answer (score 2):

**Forward server host to localhost :**

```
ssh -L localhost:22:localhost:22 user@host
```

or

```
ssh -N -f -L serverhost:22:localhost:22 user@server1
```

---

**After reading your question again.**

**You want to ssh into server1 :**

```
ssh user@server1
```

**Then you want to ssh into server2:**

Into new terminal from client do:

```
ssh user@server1
ssh user@server2
```

**Then you have 2 connections:**

1. client to server 1
2. client to server 1 ==> server 2

---

**If you want to have:**

1. client to server 1
2. client to server 2 (With same key.)

Just do following command.

**On client:**

Use tmux or open 2 terminals

```
ssh user@server1
```

In new terminal:

```
ssh user@server2
```

Comment: it didnt helped no public key error

Comment: You want to forward or 'client to server1 and client to server2?'

Comment: same pub key is stored on both server and i can ssh from client to both . now i want to use ssh agent forwarding to ssh from server 1 to 2 without private key save on server like link above

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: ur right in this case . but how can ssh from server 1 to server 2 directly without ssh from client to server 1 using key request and response . imagine server 1 system is some place else and i want ssh from that system to server 2 not from client

Comment: You can' t unless you forward from server 1 to server 2. But then you cant ssh into server 1 separately. So you have to do it manualy.

Comment: Or you use different ports. And forward from server1 (another port) to server2.

Comment: You want to ssh "from that system"  so you ALWAYS have to ssh into that system first, wherever you are. Otherwise you just dont use that system. In that system you forward to another server.

Comment: so it should be like this : a->b->c  ???

Comment: yes as i did in my answer. Read after the edit the first lines.

Comment: i did ur answer before but  i thought i can connect to server 2 from server 1 seperatly

Comment: using public key

Comment: and ssh agent forwarding but i didnt find anything on net .

Comment: If you can Edit your Question, Then I can Edit My Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to add flag `-A` like this:

`ssh -A [user]@[hostname]`

Comment: Which is also mentioned in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008070/75166) ;)

Comment: @MadMike right, but it's hard to find because of length of answer